# How to put data from ResultSet to HashMap using Lambda expression?

Tags: sql-server, lambda, hashmap, java-8

I have a table in my SQL Server 2012 Database as follows:

```
Student:
ID, CardNo, Name, ZipCode, city, ...
```

I'm writing a Java desktop application using JDK 8, in which I want to put selected rows from this table in a `HashMap` with `CardNo` as key and `Name` as value.

What's the efficient way to fill this `HashMap` using a lambda expression?

Note: `CardNo` is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler way:

```
List<Student> students = xxxDao.retrieveStudents();

Map<Integer, String> map = students.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getCardNo, Student::getName));
```

Also, you could add a static import for `Collectors.toMap` and make the expression even more readable.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
List<Student> students = xxxDao.findFromDB();
Map<String, String> map = students.stream().collect(
                                   Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCardNo, 
                                              Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                                         Collectors.mapping(Student::getName, 
                                                                    Collectors.toList()), nameList->nameList.get(0))));
```

-------------------------------------------------------split line------------------------------------------------------------------

This way I give above is much rather complex, and thanks to the @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, there is other more simple way to express what we want. Since `CardNo` is unique, just use `Collectors.toMap`

```
List<Student> students = xxxDao.findFromDB();
Map<String, String> map = students.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getCardNo, Student::getName));
```

Comment: What's the `nameList`? is there any way to use `ResulSet` directly instead of calling a function to get data?

Comment: Since `cardNo` is unique, in this case it's much better to use `Collectors.toMap()`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Oh, it's a good idea. Thank you, I am adding it now.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a lambda? Keep it simple:

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query); // assuming this

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
while(resultSet.next())
    map.put(resultSet.getString("CardNo"), resultSet.getString("Name"));
```

Using streams/lambdas is not automatically the best option, as here.

Comment: I thought that lambda should be more readable and more simple for this case, but the @Tony's answer shows the opposite.

Comment: @O.Badr yes. this is readable and easy to follow. In contrast, I would use the term "train wreck" to describe the code in Tony's answer. If code isn't readable, it is IMHO "bad".